# Area notifier in android apps

Tags: android, geolocation

[image]

Is it possible to create a program(android) that displays a `Toast` message if the user enters 'a_zone', that is to say the phone will use the current position and latitude and longitude?

```
Toast.maketext(this,"hello ",1000).show();
```

So, if the user enters an area, such as a supermarket, the application should display a message.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called Proximity alert, here is a tutorial on how to implement it :
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-proximity-alerts-tutorial.html